# Testing Parameter Restrictions in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, survival, exponential-distribution, weibull-distribution

I've got duration data that I'm analyzing in R.

The exponential and weibull distributions are both commonly used when constructing Accelerated Failure Time models for duration analysis/survival analysis.

How would one go about constructing a test of the parameter restriction that reduces the Weibull to the exponential (shape parameter =1) if I want to compare whether the data fits the Weibull or exponential better?